# CakePHP 3 query builder more conditions for one field

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I should build up an sql query from a dynamically built up form. The user will select table fileds and AND/OR logical conditions between them. So in the end I should have an SQL query like this:

```
WHERE (
  name LIKE "%foo%"
  OR name LIKE "%bar%"
)
AND (
  ad = "BP"
  OR ad = "SV"
)
```

I tried

```
$query
  ->where(['Contacts.name LIKE' => '%foo%'])
  ->orWhere(['Contacts.cname LIKE' => '%bar%'])
  ->andWhere(function($exp){
               return $exp->or_(
                          ['Contacts.ad' => 'BP'],
                          ['Contacts.ad' => 'SV']
                      );
                })
              );
```

What is clearly not good as I override Contacts.ad. I tried different ways but I was unable to get the right parenthesis.

The actual problem is more complex, as it may contain more fileds, not just this two (name and ad)

Comment: After posting my answer, I realize I may not have well understood the question... What do you mean by "What is clearly not good as I override Contacts.ad"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
$query->where(['Contacts.name LIKE' => '%foo%'])
    ->orWhere(['Contacts.cname LIKE' => '%bar%'])
    ->andWhere([
        'OR' => [
            ['Contacts.ad' => 'BP'],
            ['Contacts.ad' => 'SV']
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: Is there a way to nest a deeper level in this "OR"?